# GET https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/history/{originalTransactionId} 404

Tags: ios, http-status-code-404

when i called the apple api: [https://api.storekit-sandbox.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/history/{originalTransactionId}](https://api.storekit-sandbox.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/history/%7BoriginalTransactionId%7D) or [https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/history/{originalTransactionId}](https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/history/%7BoriginalTransactionId%7D) , http response 404

and when i check the apple document https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/get_transaction_history?language=objc , i found that,404 is(AccountNotFoundError | AccountNotFoundRetryableError | AppNotFoundError | AppNotFoundRetryableError | OriginalTransactionIdNotFoundError | OriginalTransactionIdNotFoundRetryableError)

but i only can see 404, not 404xxx ;

thanks for your help;

Comment: You question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have not replaced the `{originalTransactionId}` with the original transaction ID value provided by Apple during the purchase?

- In StoreKit v1, upon a purchase, Apple will return your app a base64 encoded string of receipt data.
- Your app will have to pass this string back to you backend service.
- Later on, from your backend, you can invoke [/verifyReceipt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt) to get decoded transaction information. In the `in_app` field of the response you will be getting a series of transactions including an *original transaction ID* for each one.
- Now you can invoke [https://api.storekit-sandbox.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/history/{originalTransactionId}](https://api.storekit-sandbox.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/history/%7BoriginalTransactionId%7D) for each transaction in the `in_app` array in the previous response, by replacing `{originalTransactionId}` with each of the *original transaction IDs* you received in the previous call.

Regarding the `404` response you received: `404` is a standard HTTP status code meaning "NOT_FOUND". In order to get more information about the error you need to inspect the HTTP response body. There, according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/get_transaction_history), you will receive an error code indicating the exact nature of the error.